# Finding a specific table with no id

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, html-table

I am working on my first selenium project and I have hit a bit of a road block. I have a webpage that contains 3 different tables. I only want to pull data from one of these tables. The problem I am facing is that bootstrap was used to style these pages, so all of the tables share the same class, and none of them have an id that I can specifically search for. I was able to do this on a different page by search for an xpath for tr/td, but that isn't working for this page because of the multiple tables. Inspecting the page source for the table I want to pull the data from I get something like the following:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-panel-heading>
      <h3 class="panel-title">table title</h3>
    </div>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>...</thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="element in main.elementService.elementTable" class="ng-scope">
          <td class="ng-binding">info1</td>
          <td class="ng-binding">info2</td>
          <td class="ng-binding">info3</td>
          <td class="ng-binding">info4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="element in main.elementService.elementTable" class="ng-scope">
        <tr ng-repeat="element in main.elementService.elementTable" class="ng-scope">
        <tr ng-repeat="element in main.elementService.elementTable" class="ng-scope">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

So this leads me to the problem that I am not sure what I can use to select only this table. If I search for `tr` or `td` I will get data from the other tables on the page as well.

The only unique feature to this table that I see is the `<div class="col-md-4">.`
I don't know if it is possible, but my idea was to do some sort of a combination search to go to this specific div and then go to the xpath tr/td to pull the data from each cell of the table, but I am new to selenium and I am not sure how to go about doing this. The documentation I am looking at does not seem to show how to combine multiple strategies together, and I am having trouble wording this for a google search, so I haven't found a google link that has given me any insight into how to do this.

I've tried something like this, but I don't think my syntax is correct

```
 List<WebElement> TableElems = chrome.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-4']//tr/td"));
```

I also tried

```
List<WebElement> TableElems = chrome.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-4']" && "//tr/td"));
```

but the `&&` operator is not allowed here.

If anyone has any ideas to tip me into the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: FYI `"col-md-4"` is the `class` attribute of the `div` not `id`...you should try with this `xPath`...`List<WebElement> TableElems = chrome.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-4']/descendant::td"));`

Comment: I have edited, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this xpath expression:

```
"//div[@class='col-md-4']//tr/td"
```

The difference to your attempt is the use of the `class` attribute (there is no id) and the double slash before `tr` which allows the `tr` to be a descendant element of `div[@id='col-md-4']` in any depth and not just a direct child.

Comment: I've made these edits. I don't think this is the correct approach - it's still not doing anything.

Comment: @JMullen this is hard to reproduce given your data. But anyway you should really invest in learning either XPath expressions or CSS selectors (see answer of @Carele). Else you are just lost in blind attempts to get a solution.

Comment: Hi - I take that back. I made an error in my edit. This is correct - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to used the "find_element_by_css_selector" method instead. You can use the CSS selector "nth-child" too if you happen to a similar problem where you don't have a specific class.
With class :

```
By.css(".col-md-4 tr > td")
```

If all the table have col-md-4 class, if you want the third table of a page :

```
By.css(".col-md-4:nth-child(3) tr > td")
```

Also, you give to your xpath request the `id` attribute, but "col-md-4" is a `class`, be careful.

Comment: What is the `>` character doing here? I am new to selenium and I am learning the syntax. I haven't seen this yet.

Comment: This is a CSS selector to say that the second class is a direct child from the first (whereas if you don't use it, you select any td descendant from a td even if that tr is in another div or something like that). If you want to get any td under a tr, suppress it. Else, you can omit it, but anytime i can add them, i do. It's an extra security.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`//table[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@id), " "), " table-striped table-bordered"][//td[contains(text() , "info1")]])[1]`

Comment: Could you please explain this?

Comment: by table contains you search for table class with name "table-striped talbe-bordered" , so you won't search for whole document.
Then you search in td for td which contains text "info1" and  by [1] you pick it 1st element

Answer (score 0):

you can use below xpath to get the values of each table by their position.

```
.//table[1]/descendant::tr/td -for table 1
.//table[2]/descendant::tr/td -for table 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Xpath

```
 /html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[text()='info3']/../../..
```

if you are trying to select the table , in case you want to select the td 
remove the rest after the td[text()='info3']

Answer (score 0):

What I ususally do in these situations is find the table elements first:

```
List<WebElement> tables = (List<WebElement>)chrome.findElements(By.className("table-responsive"));
```

Then get the exact table you want:

```
WebElement table = tables.get(i);
```

You can repeat this and use loops to get down to the exact data you want.

```
List<WebElement> dataElements = (List<WebElement>)chrome.findElements(By.className("ng-binding"));
for (int i=0; i<dataElements.size(); i++) {
    String data = dataElements.get(i).getText();
    //Do something with data
}
```